# Is there any standard way to report errors in desktop application?

Tags: .net, wpf, error-handling

Is there any standard system or .NET API for reporting errors occured in WPF application, or you must always implement custom solution?

Comment: Do you mean reporting errors to the UI or to some log?

Comment: Something like Windows Error Reporting, but tailored to your application.

Comment: So some error reporting API/framework, NOT logging framework like log4net.

Answer (score 0):

What about log4net? https://logging.apache.org/log4net/

It allows you to output to multiple logging targets:

1. Writes logging events to a database using either prepared statements or stored procedures.
2. Writes color highlighted logging events to a an ANSI terminal window.
3. Writes logging events to the ASP trace context. These can then be rendered at the end of the ASP page or on the ASP trace page.
4. Writes color highlighted logging events to the application's Windows Console.
5. Writes logging events to the application's Console. The events may go to either the standard our stream or the standard error stream.
6. Writes logging events to the .NET system.
7. Writes logging events to the Windows Event Log.
8. Writes logging events to a file in the file system.
9. Writes logging events to the local syslog service (UNIX only).
10. Stores logging events in an in memory buffer.
11. Writes logging events to the Windows Messenger service. These messages are displayed in a dialog on a users terminal.
12. Writes logging events to the debugger. If the application has no debugger, the system debugger displays the string. If the application has no debugger and the system debugger is not active, the message is ignored.
13. Writes logging events to a remote syslog service using UDP networking.
14. Writes logging events to a remoting sink using .NET remoting.
15. Writes logging events to a file in the file system. The RollingFileAppender can be configured to log to multiple files based upon date or file size constraints.
16. Sends logging events to an email address.
17. Sends logging events to an email address but writes the emails to a configurable directory rather than sending them directly via SMTP.
18. Clients connect via Telnet to receive logging events.
19. Writes logging events to the .NET trace system.
20. Sends logging events as connectionless UDP datagrams to a remote host or a multicast group using a UdpClient.

Answer (score -2):

The way  I know is when you catch an error, like so:

```
try
   {
   ....
   }

 catch (Exception exception) // catching a general exception is usually a bad idea, would be good to specialise it like FormatException
   {            
   MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString()); // this is usefull when debugging to see exactly what happened     
    throw;              
   }
```

For logging these errors, theres is polenty of methods online, if you do a google search to put them all in a notepad, in your application folder, then when there is a client crash, you can add a pop up window, asking the user to email you the notepad , kind of like when windows asks to send an error report

Update: From the research I have done, only custom solutions were found

Comment: Disclamer: I'm not the downvoter. I wouldn't use `exceptionName` as identifier, but just `exception`. In the other hand, after showing the message box, you should re-throw the exception (i.e. `throw;`). BTW, your suggestion is very limited, I guess OP knew this before asking for a potential solution...

Comment: @Matias, yeah well as you can see from my rep, Im still learning, this is just what I found from researching. OP doesn't seem to have any idea what to do, so was just giving a starter idea

Comment: Ok, I give you a suggestion even for you. A better error reporting would be done using `AppDomain.UnhandledException` and reporting it to the Windows Event Log :D

Comment: @Matias, thanks for that, I will have to research that :) sounds good

Comment: I am not asking about how to catch exception!

Comment: @Ondrej, but that's the initial stage of reporting an error, as that is what an error is, if you wanted a clearer answer, you should have asked a clearer question..

Comment: @JohnChris Does "Is there any standard system or .NET API for reporting errors" have something related to catching exceptions?

Comment: @ Ondrej, a system means everything , which would include catching exceptions, if someone asked how does the financial system work, would you not start by teaching them the basics?